# Find numbers in a string not preceded or followed by any letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

im not all that familiar with regular expressions. 
im trying to figure out how to find a number in a string that is not preceded or followed by a letter with javascript

```
s= "sc010sc"
//shouldnt return 

s = "x0001"
//shouldnt return 

s = "thing_0001_5642"
//return [0001, 5642]



s = "05012"
//return 05012
```

Comment: Any particular programming language or regex dialect?

Comment: Try `(?<![0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9]+(?![0-9a-zA-Z])`

Comment: i should have mentioned im  using javascript

Comment: This is an excellent reference page for REGEX with Javascipt:
(REGEX)[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp]

Comment: Why the first case shouldn't find `"1"`? That is a number preceded and followed by `"0"`, not a letter.

Comment: Try `/(^|[^a-z0-9])(\d+)(?![0-9a-z])/ig` or even with a `\b` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that did work except for that it includes the underscores in the match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
var rx = /(?:^|[^a-z0-9])(\d+)(?![0-9a-z])/ig;
var s = "thing_0001_5642";// with "sc010sc" it does not return any result
var res = [];
while((m=rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
 res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^|[^a-z0-9])` - either start of string or non-digit and non-letter
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `(?![0-9a-z])` - that are not followed with a digit or letter.

Since the `/i` modifier is used, all ASCII letters are matched with `[a-z]`.

As we need to access *captured values*, I am using a `RegExp#exec` in a loop to only grab `match[1]` value.

Comment: thanks a bunch and the explanation. not sure why it has two captures though

Comment: The expression has only 1 capture group. The `m` Match object has 2 items: `m[0]` contains the whole match, and `m[1]` contains Capture group 1 value.